# Effects of decreasing the field voltage of a synchronous machine

Tags: analysis, electric-machine, synchronous, synchronous-motor

I am running a simulation of a synchronous machine in matlab and I have some behaviour I cant quite grasp my head around. The machine is running as a motor with only about 20% of its maximum load, armature voltage and load are kept the same throughout my experiment. What I cant understand is:

.If I step the field voltage to 50% I see an increase in armature current, an increase in field current, an increase in load angle the rotation speed also goes up before coming down again.

.If I step the opposite will happen.

This picture shows what happens when field voltage decreases to 50%.
(the change happens at 1 second)

[image: decreace of field voltage to 50%]

This picture shows what happens when field voltage increases to 150%.
(the change happens at 1 second)

[image]

I dont understand the behaviour of these variables, why would the field current ever increase with a drop of field voltage, why would that affect the load angle?

Comment: good so far ... now how about asking a question? What bit of the behaviour don't you understand?

Comment: There is a lot I dont understand, isnt the field current supposed to fall with the drop in voltage, I see it increasing in both situations, why would the load angle change?

Comment: Where is the field current in the diagrams? I agree, the field current is controlled by the field voltage.

Comment: You say that the load is held constant. I assume you are talking about the mechanical load torque being held constant, right? I guess that when you reduce the field, the back emf decreases, and so the armature current increases, and the load angle increases. This is needed to maintain sufficient torque for synchronous operation. If you continue to reduce the field, I assume at some point the motor will be unable to drive the mechanical load at full speed and you will lose synchronization. I am not clear on why the field current increases, but I am not experienced with this type of machine.

Comment: The curves look like curves for a machine operating as a generator. I suspect that there is a problem with setting the inputs to the simulation and possibly also with displaying or identifying the operating parameters. Both the real and reactive components of the electrical power should be displayed.